# Return two tables from a stored procedure from LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have written a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProcedure] 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 CampaignID FROM Campaigns   
SELECT TOP 1 ServiceID FROM Services ORDER BY ServiceID desc
END
```

In my .NET Project, I have a LINQ to SQL file (`.dbml`) and I have drag-and-dropped this procedure to create a new class `TestProcedureResult`:

```
Partial Public Class TestProcedureResult

        Private _CampaignID As Integer

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
        End Sub

        <Column(Storage:="_CampaignID", DbType:="Int NOT NULL")>  _
        Public Property CampaignID() As Integer
            Get
                Return Me._CampaignID
            End Get
            Set
                If ((Me._CampaignID = value)  _
                            = false) Then
                    Me._CampaignID = value
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

So it is not returning `ServiceID`. How can I retreive `ServiceID` using LINQ to SQL?
I know we can customize stored procedure calls, but how can I customize in this particular scenario?

Comment: I know that Linq-SQL can cope with usps, but it's still at the end of the day an ORM, whereas this smacks of straightforward ADO.net.

Comment: Thanks Bony.i know that is very simple in ado.net but i want to know how we will do it Linq to sql and how can i catch this results in .net?

Comment: You are making your life hard, for no discernible benefit - this is not the kind of thing ORM's are designed for. If you want to use Linq-to SQL you should be going via the Campaign and Service entities instead of using a usp. If you want to use a usp then it will be more performant, easier to read, and all round better practise to use ADO.net.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you can't use the drag-drop designer to create the code for you.

Try these articles:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dditweb/archive/2008/05/06/linq-to-sql-and-multiple-result-sets-in-stored-procedures.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx